# How to create setter and getter for a custom view in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, view

I am building a custom view that extends view and take parameter for image. So far I have been to achieve drawing the image from a drawable and server (through string URL).

```
class CustomView(context: Context, attrSet: AttributeSet) : View(context){

    private var typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrSet, R.styleable.CustomView)
    private var viewColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.CustomView_viewColor, Color.WHITE)
    private var viewSize = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CustomView_viewSize, 200)
    private var rect = Rect(50, 50, this.left+viewSize, this.top+viewSize)
    var viewImage = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomView_viewImage, -1)
    var imageBitmap:Bitmap?=null
    var imageString = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.CustomView_imageString)


    val radius = 100f
    var cx = 0f
    var cy = 0f
    private var paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private var circlePaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private var labelPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    init {

        paint.color = viewColor
        circlePaint.color = Color.parseColor("#000000")
        labelPaint.color = Color.parseColor("#000000")
        typedArray.recycle()
        try {
            val iStream = URL(imageString)
            imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, viewImage) ?: BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream.openStream())

        }catch (e:Exception){
            Log.i("Image", "Kindly provide a valid image")
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {

        if(cx == 0f || cy == 0f){
            cx = (width/2).toFloat()
            cy = (height/2).toFloat()
        }

        canvas?.drawRect(rect, paint)
        canvas?.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, circlePaint)

        if (imageBitmap != null){
            canvas?.drawBitmap(imageBitmap!!, 50f, 100f, null)
        }
    }
}
```

I also want to be able to change this value at runtime outside the xml, like in an activity or fragment to make it dynamic.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val url =
            "https://dyl80ryjxr1ke.cloudfront.net/external_assets/hero_examples/hair_beach_v1785392215/original.jpeg"
        customView.imageString = url
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in class CustomView make the line in init function a setup function like below :

```
class CustomView(context: Context, attrSet: AttributeSet) : View(context) {
    //setups

    init()
    {
        setupFunction(imageString)
    }

    fun setupFunction(url: String) {
        paint.color = viewColor
        circlePaint.color = Color.parseColor("#000000")
        labelPaint.color = Color.parseColor("#000000")
        typedArray.recycle()
        try {
            val iStream = URL(imageString)
            imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, viewImage)
                ?: BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream.openStream())

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.i("Image", "Kindly provide a valid image")
        }
    }
    onDraw()
}
```

now setupFunction() could be called from your Fragment or Activity every time you want like this :

```
customView.setupFunction(url)
```

and the view will be initiated as you want.

Comment: I tried this and get ```Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.decagon.calabashtest.CustomView.setupFunc(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference```

Comment: Where have you called it?because this is telling you that customView has not been created.

Comment: yeah. I figured that I didn't include attributeset in the super class. When I did the error disappear but the image is not changing.

Comment: ok I think the redraw will be happened by calling the draw function in setup function. I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help @Bita I used postInvalidate() and it worked. I don't think onDraw() will because I have to pass canvas into it. Thanks a lot.